# Android: How to get thumbnail of video private to app

Tags: android

Is it possible to get a video thumbnail from a video that is private to your app? (thats probably the best way to explain it)

I have an app which runs exclusively on a 4.3 device of which the user has no control over. Therefore, the standard getvideothumbnail() function doesn't work as the function requires the user to actually look at the file before creating a thumbnail accessible to other apps.

So, if an app autonomously downloads a video, and the user has no interaction to make android create a thumbnail, how can I obtain a thumbnail?

thank you for any help.